# Ajax: send mulit images

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I use  laravel and I want to upload gallery and I want to use ajax.
I created this code

```
$('#hello').on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData(this);
      $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: "{{ route('upload.store')}}",
          mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
         headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
         },
         data: formData,
         success: function(done){
           console.log(done)
         },
         error: function(error){
           console.log(error);
         }
       });
    });
```

This is ma the latest code. Could you help me?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#hello').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    var formData = new FormData($("#hello")[0]);

    $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('upload.store')}}",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(done){
              console.log(done)
            },
            error: function(error){
              console.log(error);
            }
        });

});
```